# OutOfMemoryException when rendering TextBlock using WriteableBitmapEx

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a fight with the `OutOfMemoryException` again.

I have code snippet to render some images by using [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) in a Windows Phone background agent task (which have a memory usage limit approach to 10M).

The following works just fine:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    var wbBG = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0);
    var bmp = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            wbBG = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromContent("Assets/image" + i + ".jpg");                          
            wbBG.Invalidate();

            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromContent("Assets/" + j + ".png");
                bmp = bmp.Resize(60, 60, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

                wbBG.Blit(new Rect(j * 65, 0, 60, 60), bmp, new Rect(0, 0, 60, 60));
                wbBG.Invalidate();
            }
            string filenameBG = "/Shared/" + i + ".jpg";
            using (var stream = iso.CreateFile(filenameBG))
            {
                wbBG.SaveJpeg(stream, 480, 800, 0, 85);
                stream.Close();
            }
            wbBG = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
    NotifyComplete();
});
```

However, if I add or change to use a `TextBlock` in the loop, it will fail in the 2nd loop with`OutOfMemoryException`:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    var wbBG = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0);
    TextBlock tb;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            wbBG = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromContent("Assets/image" + i + ".jpg"); 
                            //The above line would thrown OutOfMemoryException in the 2nd loop                       
            wbBG.Invalidate();

            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                tb = new TextBlock(){
                    Text = j.ToString(),
                    //FontSize = 13,
                    //Height = 20,
                    //Width = 240,
                    //FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold,
                    //HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    //Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
                };
                wbBG.Render(tb, new TranslateTransform() { X = j*65, Y = 350 });
                wbBG.Invalidate();
                tb = null;
            }
            string filenameBG = "/Shared/" + i + ".jpg";
            using (var stream = iso.CreateFile(filenameBG))
            {
                wbBG.SaveJpeg(stream, 480, 800, 0, 85);
                stream.Close();
            }
            wbBG = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
    NotifyComplete();
});
```

Any idea why a `TextBlock` would cause more memory usage?

Furthermore, I don't see there are better method to render text on the images.

Also the `TextBlock` is not `IDisposable`.

Well, that's my opinions, probably wrong, I'd appreciate any help, thank!

Comment: What is `BitmapFactory`?

Comment: You do realize you are trying to render 30 images and you have 180 `Render` calls? Also, why don't you *construct* the control in the inner loop and reducing 6 calls to one? Plus if you load the image *once* before the first loop, you wouldn't load it 30 times.

Comment: Then why did the first one work? BTW, I have to load different image in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library but you have forgot to release the resources when they aren't in use anymore so try this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var wbBG = BitmapFactory.New(0, 0).FromContent("Assets/image" + i + ".jpg"))
                {
                    wbBG.Invalidate();

                    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                    {
                        var tb = new TextBlock()
                        {
                            Text = j.ToString(),
                            //FontSize = 13,
                            //Height = 20,
                            //Width = 240,
                            //FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold,
                            //HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                            //Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
                        };
                        wbBG.Render(tb, new TranslateTransform() { X = j * 65, Y = 350 });
                        wbBG.Invalidate();
                    }
                    using (var stream = iso.CreateFile("/Shared/" + i + ".jpg"))
                    {
                        wbBG.SaveJpeg(stream, 480, 800, 0, 85);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for trying to help, and sorry for the delay reply, I was stuck by some urgent task.
Yes, I agree that I need to release the resources that I used, however, the BitmapFactory(`WriteableBitmap`) as well as the `TextBlock` are not `IDisposable`, thus I cannot use the `using` block or `Close()` method.